# SQL сервер сохраняет удаленные BLOB данные

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, blob

Я сохраняю картинки в формате BLOB в SQL таблицу на сервере ubuntu, а после того, как я их удаляю через DELETE FROM pictures WHERE id = ? они удаляются с таблицы, но почему то память все равно занимается, и мне приходится сбрасывать весь сервер, чтобы ее отчистить. Как это пофиксить? Нужно сделать так, чтобы когда я удалял строку из таблицы память отчищалась.

imgur.com/kA0NuT9 Вот об этой памяти идет речь

Comment: Не надо сохранять картинки в базу, сохраняйте в файлы

Comment: Вам уже писали: используйте Shrink.

Comment: ...ах вот почему вопрос мне знакомым показался